# Recursive Descent Parser Help (Not reading a text file string)

Tags: c++

```
char input[100]; //Used to check grammar
char *s;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    ifstream fin("input.txt");  //Open input file
    while (fin>>input) {  //Store text in input[]
        s = input;  //Point c at the input text

        cout<<"String read from file:  "<<input<<endl;  //Show input text
        if (A() && *s == '\0') {  //Testing the grammar
            cout<<"The string \""<<input<<"\" is in the language."<<endl;
        }
        else cout<<"The string \""<<input<<"\" is not in the language."<<endl;
        cout<<endl;  //Formatting for output in console
    }
    fin.close();  //Close input file


    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here. The parser is not reading string from the text file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take a little time to read the guidelines about how to write acceptable questions at the [help].   "How to ask" and "MVCE" are important.   A key element missing from your question as it stands is ... what is your question?  What are the symptoms of the problem?  What were you expecting?

Comment: Yes sir i am very new to this forum and wondering if someone can help i just need to know how to parse from a text file.

Comment: What does `A()` do? You haven't show the code for that.

Comment: To improve your question, you need to share why you think it is not reading string from the text file.   You also need to get rid of code that is not related to that.  Half the time, by the time you've done this, you'll have solved your own problem.  If you haven't, then you need to provide an MCVE: code that we can run, that doesn't call anything we don't have.

Comment: Do i need to use getline function from file and then use pointer pointing to that ?

Comment: You're not parsing anything here . Why confuse people with that title? May be just say you're unable to read data from file into a string ?

Comment: :) you have to show the definition of A() not declaration.

Comment: I have BNF grammar that i need to parse and one of that A is /* A -> I = E | E */

Comment: Please edit your exact program output into the question. Are you seeing `"Sting read from file: "`? If not, you may be failing to open the file: you should be checking that (I tend to use `if (ifstream fin("input.txt")) { ... } else std::cerr << "unable to open input file\n";`).  Note that `>>` defaults to reading a whitespace-delimited token - you can use `getline()` for other delimiteres (the default being a newline / `\n`). It's much better to use `std::string` and avoid globals too, but judging from what you're doing now that might be a significant rewrite for you....

Answer (score 1):

Let's treat this like two problems.

Problem 1: Reading in the file.

I've stripped out everything that isn't absolutely essential to reading the data in.

```
char input[100]; //Used to check grammar

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    ifstream fin("input.txt");  //Open input file
    while (fin>>input) {  //Store text in input[]
        cout<<"String read from file:  "<<input<<endl;  //Show input text
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Nothing really wrong here, but you should seriously consider replacing `char input[100];` with `std::string input;` to save you headaches with large tokens. For example, watch what happens here:

```
int main()
{
    stringstream stream("1234567890"); // pack ten characters into stream
                                       // note: no whitespace.
    char snookums[] = "snookums";
    char array[5];
    cout << snookums << endl; // prove contents of snookums
    stream >> array; // read up to first whitespace from stream into array
    cout << array << endl;  // display what we read.  
    cout << snookums << endl; // oh dear. Now look at poor snookums!
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
snookums
1234567890
67890
```

Despite array being size 5, it contains all 10. Or does it? Nope. Sadly poor snookums got run over. This won't happen with strings.

For all we know `fin>>input`just read 30000 characters from a whitespace-free file, annihilated the rest of your program's memory, and the program died before printing out anything.

Anyway, your code leaves a few questions:

Are you actually able to open the file? You don't know, really. You never checked.

Was the file empty? Also don't know. You didn't tell us. This is one of the things folks are getting on about in the comments.

None of this fixes anything, but hopefully gives you a better idea what's going wrong.

```
string input; // using string in case the data you're reading is incompatible 
              //with a 100 character char array. 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    ifstream fin("input.txt");  //Open input file
    if (fin.is_open()
    {
        while (fin>>input) 
        {  //Store text in input
            cout<<"String read from file:  "<<input<<endl;  //Show input text
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failed to open file." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Once you know if you are actually reading in data, and if not, why not.

Problem 2: language parsing.

We can't help you here. No information was provided, but a few notes on coding style because they will help you ask future questions:

`A()` is meaningless to everyone but you. Give it a descriptive name so that someone other than you has some hints about what it does. `A()` takes no parameters. I assume that's because it is operating on `input`. OK, but why not pass `input` in? The cost is minimal and it provides more information to readers. Note how commenters zeroed in on `A()` right away? That's fear. The good kind of fear. We have no [insert expletive here] clue what it is or what it does, so it is instantly scrutinized.

`A(input)` reads to me as "A does something to input." I don't know what it does, but it does it to `input`. Unless the writer of the program has a history of doing silly stuff, it probably only does stuff to `input` and I don't have to fear this function nearly as much.

`LanguageInterpreter()` tells me that a language interpreter was run. Not much, but if I'm looking tor a bug in the file reading code, I'm not likely to find it in there. Unfortunately it also tells me that LanguageInterpreter is feasting on global data and Crom only knows what sort of side effects it could have on the rest of the program.

`LanguageInterpretter(input)` tells me a lot. For one thing it tells me that I can get on with my day because it has nothing to do with, or better have nothing to do with, the reading in of the data file. I'll check other places for bugs first.

Comment: I am able to read the file and then also have pointer point to that particular string but now i am stuck at this part if (A() && *s == '\0')  and i am getting an error

Comment: @JonAbraham A C++ string does not work quite the same as a C string. To test for an empty string just call the `empty` method. `A() && !input.empty()`. I doubt you need `s`. [Read up on strings.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: Okay moving on so i tried what you mentioned and that part is not showing any error now.

Answer (score 0):

```html
string *s;

int main() 
{
 string input;
    ifstream fin("input.txt"); 
 
 if(fin.is_open())
 {  
  while(getline(fin,input))
  {
   s=&input;
   
   if (A() && *s == '\0') /* error: no match for 'operator==' in '* s == '\000''*/



   {  //Testing the grammar
    cout<<"The string \""<<*s<<"\" is in the language."<<endl;
   }
   else cout<<"The string \""<<*s<<"\" is not in the language."<<endl;
   cout<<endl;  
   
   
  }
 }
    fin.close();  
 
    
    return 0;
}
```